# "process lines containing" Feature in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, textwrangler, bbedit

In TextWrangler and BBEdit there is a "process lines containing" function. Does anyone know if this is available in Notepad++? I haven't been able to find it yet, if so.

Alternatively, does other PC software exist that might have this option?

Comment: What "processing" do you want to do on the lines? Your question is not at all clear. Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve and what you have already tried. Please also read the [help] pages on what sort of questions are on topic here, note that asking for software recommendations is off topic and may lead to your question being closed.

Comment: Hi AdrianHHH, in TextWrangler you can use the "process lines containing" function to output any and/or every line into its own txt file. So, for example, if I have one line with "the dog sits." and another with "he jumps." I could use the "process lines containing" function to save each line that ends with a period to its own txt file. I am looking for this sort of feature in Notepad++ and, if it doesn't exist there, in something comparable.

Comment: Your *Alternatively* paragraph is totally off-topic here. We don't recommend software here. Your first paragraph is too vague. I'm not familiar with either TextWrangler or BBEdit, but I'm quite familiar with Notepad++. If you don't clearly and specifically describe the functionality you're looking for, it's impossible to determine whether it exists or not. It's pointless to say *This thing has a feature called Fribble. I'm not going to tell you what it does, but does that thing have a feature like it?*. Be **specific** about what you're asking if you want help here, and in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the processing wanted in your comment, use the search command, select the `Mark` tab, make sure that that you have ticked `Bookmark line` enter the search string and click on `Mark All`. Observe that the wanted lines have blue blobs at their left hand ends. These can be click on or off to modify individual bookmarks. Use the menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Copy bookmarked lines** and then paste them into another buffer.